# Does Neural Net with Softmax activation function violate the IIA assumption?

Tags: neural-networks, multinomial-logit

Multinomial logistic regression have assume the IIA (independence of irrelevant alternatives (IIA), [IIA assumption: difference logit and probit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147489/iia-assumption-difference-logit-and-probit)); but I'm wondering if using Neural network in which the last layer has Softmax activation with negative-log-likelihood as loss function and perform gradient descent also assumes IIA?

If so; is there anyway of make neural net violates IIA ?

Comment: What is "the IIA"?

Comment: @Sycorax I've updated the post to include IIA